# How to generate an underdamped oscillation using transformers?

Tags: transformer, oscillation

We want to generate an underdamped oscillation with a transformer, with this circuit:

[image: Underdamped oscillation]

I am able to generate this signal:

[image: Underdamped oscillations]

But I want to use a transformer instead something like this:

[image]

What should I be doing to get the underdamped oscillations as above?

Sid

Comment: Tuning either of the windings (or both) with a suitable capacitor.